# Colours in Pie chart doesnt respect settings

Tags: javascript, react-google-charts

We ve set pie chart and I want to change the colours of bars, but they are still same
[I wanr different colours than this ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udo26.png). It should be olive/khaki...

```
 google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {



   work = <xsl:value-of select="$holidayPay"/>; //Yearly Netto Salary
   eat = <xsl:value-of select="$totalCost"/>; //odvody SS na sociální a zdravotní pojištění
   commute = <xsl:value-of select="$yearlyBonusPayment"/>; //Annual Bonus
   tv = <xsl:value-of select="$pensionContribution"/>+<xsl:value-of select="$cafeteriaContribution"/>+<xsl:value-of select="$lunchContribution"/>+<xsl:value-of select="$customField2"/>+<xsl:value-of select="$Referral"/>; //Benefits Contribution 
   tc = <xsl:value-of select="$travelPay"/>+<xsl:value-of select="$sicknessPay"/>+<xsl:value-of select="$TrainingCosts"/>; //Training Costs
 

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Task', 'Hours per Week'],
      ['Yearly Netto Salary',    work],
      ['Look, what the state has stolen from your payslip',      eat],
      ['Annual Bonus',  commute],
      ['Benefits Contribution', tv],
      ['Training Costs', tc],

    ]);

    var options = {
      //title: 'Weekly Activities',
      colors: ['olive','darkolivegreen','khaki','darkkhaki','cornsilk']

    };


    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, null);

  }
```

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Please read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what does it mean: the colors are the same? same as what?